# Logged user outside firewall in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

lemme explain my problem - i wanna develop e-shop in symfony, but i dont know how to configure firewalls. Normally, i use firewall to restrict access in secured areas, like pages administration, but this time some pages should be accessible without login and in case user logs in, i wanna to get his info on those pages.

I can use two firewalls with different providers, one for admins and another for users. But - how to set security to have accessible user's data on pages, that are not under firewall?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Several ways to accomplish this, In your twig template [`{% if app.user is not null and is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#access-control-in-templates) of the protected content of the page, or in your controller create a separate action method for logged in users and those that are not with the [`@Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html) annotation

Answer (score 0):

That is not what symfony firewalls are for. Firewalls are for Access Validation. Not View Validation.

You want to check the user (if logged in) in the view and show the data.

If the data changes dependend on the user (e.g. different prices), you'll have to check the user inside the controller.